# Flutter splashScreen for Android how do I change the background color

Tags: flutter

I want to change the splashScreen for my flutter app android version. I have checked in youtube and in even in the older post here in stackOverFlow, I have followed the steps but the thing is that my `colors.xml` is not being recognized when I start the app I get the white splashScreen for some second.

I have attached the screenshot:
here is the `colors.xml` file
[image]

here is the `launch_background.xml` file
[image]

you can clearly see that my `colors.xml` file value is not being recognized.

I am new to flutter and I tried to refer the Doc but its all jumble up for me, not able to figure the head and tail out there, so can anybody please help me out. I know its quite simple for you all.

Please any expertise thank you in advance.

I have also tried the invalid/Caches Restarted the studio too still no result.

this is my `main.dart`:

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    // This widget is the root of your application.
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home:splash(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{'/1': (BuildContext context) => 
      splashScreen()},
      );
     }
    }
```

this my `splash.dart`:

```
// ignore: camel_case_types
class _splashState extends State<splash> {

 @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  startTime();
  }

startTime() async{
  var duration = Duration(seconds: 2);
  return Timer(duration, navigationPage);
 }

void navigationPage(){
 Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/1');
}

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: myColors.myBackColor,
  );
}
}
```

this is my `splashScreen.dart`:

```
class splashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _splashScreenState createState() => _splashScreenState();
 }

// ignore: camel_case_types
class _splashScreenState extends State<splashScreen> with 
SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{

 AnimationController _animationController;
 Animation _animation;
 double top= 600.0;
 AlignmentTween _alignmentTween;
 Text _text;

 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   _animationController= AnimationController(
     vsync: this,
     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600));
   _animationController.forward();
   _animation= CurvedAnimation(
       parent: _animationController,
       curve: Curves.easeIn);
   _alignmentTween= AlignmentTween(begin: Alignment.bottomCenter, end: 
   Alignment.topCenter);
   _text= Text('MyApp Name',style: TextStyle(
     fontSize: myFontSize.titleName,
     color: myColors.mySplashTitleColor,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     fontFamily: 'acme',
     letterSpacing: 2.0,
   ));
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   String key;

   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: myColors.myBackColor,
     body: TweenAnimationBuilder(
       key: Key(key),
       child: Align(
         alignment: Alignment(0,.6),
           child: _text),
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
       tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0),
       builder: (context, double val,Widget child){
         return Opacity(opacity: val,
         child: child,);
       },
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

the above code I have found on youtube and some blog I tried editing so that I could understand what was going on, then when I thought about the splashscreen it was `white color` I was trying to change it then I have refer to youtube and some older post from StackOverFlow, follow the same steps but I was unable to change it.

result which I get:

[image]

Comment: Just change the color in colors.xml and run. It's fine.

Comment: @OMiShah I have tried just now, I still get the white splashScreen when I start the app

Comment: Did you run flutter clean ?

Comment: you mean in ternimal?

Comment: @RobertSandberg Yup just now I have tried, I still get the white screen when I open the app.

Comment: is it  because of something that I have typed wrongly

Comment: You should not paste images, but rather paste the code. Easier to help you. You have commented out the part the would make it work.

Comment: Okay, give me a second

Comment: @RobertSandberg I have shared the code, I bet there is something that I have typed wrong which I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

In ./values/colors.xml :

```
<resources>
    <color name="launcher_background_color">#FFCA28</color>
</resources>
```

In ./drawable/launch_background.xml :

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/launcher_background_color" />
</layer-list>
```

`flutter clean` in terminal and rebuild

[image]

Comment: I have tried the same but I still get the white color for few seconds.

Comment: I literally just created a fresh project, with those as the only changes. And this will give a yellow-ish screen. Are you running on an Android device, and not accidentally started an IOS device? :) (I actually made that mistake when I tested now.)

Comment: Yes, I am trying to run on an android device, yes I didn't start an IOS device..

Comment: android device with api level 22

Comment: It always happens with me always get stuck on the simplest code.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to get the yellow-ish splashScreen when I try to start the app

Comment: Try creating a fresh, brand new project and make sure you get that to work. Then see what the possible differences are between your new project and your existing one.

Comment: it works!! thanks, I don't know what went wrong everything seen to be the same. I have made a new project with the same code and it works

Comment: Awesome! Mark the answer as accepted / completed / solved.

Comment: Can you check this one too?? "https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730746?noredirect=1"

Answer (score 2):

Change launch_background.xml in both paths

1. /app/src/main/res/drawable-v21
2. /app/src/main/res/drawable